# Kraken.js - yo kraken Error kraken primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, kraken.js

I have installed Kraken.js with the following command:

```
npm install -g yo generator-kraken bower grunt-cli
```

After the installation, when executing the command `yo kraken` I get the following error:

```
$ yo kraken
Error kraken

primordials is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Below steps resolved the same issue for me on Ubuntu,

```sh
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 11.15.0
npm install gulp@^3.9.1
yo kraken
```

The error seems to be a conflict with gulp and node version